# Outlook email is scrambled (Looks like Encryption Junk) on forward

Tags: windows-xp, email, encryption, microsoft-outlook-2003

OS: Windows XP SP3 Email Client: Outlook 2003

Recently the place were I work has had an issue. One of our employees can receive email just fine, but sometimes when forwarding it, it turns into a gabled mess. It looks like encryption junk.

```
(½š«
a;¨jú½ýQÚ£•@J!œw~ üä7Ñ¿áI¶&3* nè&„W% ‘Áþ´=¡â,qì êât“p|N„‡Û¹1·Äæyç‹.lïßFïQ÷=ÉÒÁ äW , {?XÂì%,35Ç‹b  w(èa…êö "qò { ìHšLªƒHWLÜl‡^léàÊDˆÕQÓçkÅ*ŽÖ½ ã½\wl–¢˜Þ…0<< ]w2 Dý+ =ó¨co!wÕ ·¥I…  ÀóUƒ >â)Á'š±EÕø ýbr `…/  ê+9ª«? Ã[™ž±dXB^W;M¨BÂÈ²Zdˆ ò½ÙŽ‚0*ÒV r †BÉ`6„:æs :ì  öÚIÀ-
 Äd²l©vm§
À »‚  óhÅú €O Õá¤å™:!Ördý±%6ŸSxÐôÚ }¸  àëàó› ˜Ø‘
®  œ  .µ¨¶&B'Y] _³”åµü07º ÛÛÖ,ÚJªó0gýuõ½ÅT  + « ü"Ê% õ]ôÍïEÍ ä*!‘u ï&^K ÀE îoaì3€Z‘1 €Qð&
5‹É   °×ŒþúçÂtáX;nuÝðÀ.üÛ|Öú ×}5$¨þ|Úuú
¥9½Üo¸ýís ¦o+„¿ì ÿc^ À,Y)^BV&ŸFa_ 7Ó­tÌY ý—féš—Ñ·Íä›Ã
```

What makes this odd is that attachments are just fine. It's just the text that gets nuked.

I looked at Add-in but didn't see anything that would do any sort of encryption. It's also odd that it only encrypts the message and not the attachments.

I've searched around the internet and haven't found a solution so, I figured I'd try here.

Comment: That's rather encoding problem. I got something like that but with Chinese characters sometimes.

Comment: I had this happen to 10k emails back about a decade ago when I used, an anti-virus outlook plugin, that scanned then proceeded to corrupt every single one of my emails.  This is something only the IT department at your work can fix.

Comment: My problem is that I AM the IT department. It's a small horribly out of date shop.

Answer (score 0):

This was a big problem back in my Wells Fargo Help Desk days. You're able to define the format in which you write emails. Emails you compose, Forward, Reply, etc. They can all be defined differently. It sounds like the original email you received was in a rich text format, and your "Forwarding" format for your emails are set to plain / standard text. It's a setting in your Outlook preferences. Use these directions to double check:
http://www.uwec.edu/help/outlook03/MAIL-formatting.htm

Comment: My next day at that office is Tuesday, so I'll report back after I check it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, it wasn't a formatting issue. It turns out that it was a bad DLL. Uninstalling and then Installing Outlook 2003 fixed the issue.